# Browser version on api 16 -18 on genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

Is there a way to check the version of browser on android devices with API level 16-19(Android 4.1 to 4.3) when calling the webview? I can't seem to get the browser version using developer tools on chrome.I have read that dev tools are only for android 4.4 and up, but is there a workaround?

TYIM!